# How do I fix dimension error in a simple Autoencoder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am new to python and autoencoders. I just wanted to build a simple autoencoder to start with, but I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_39 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 3)
```

Is there a better way to get my own data, besides the `flow_from_directory` method? I built the Autoencoder like [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/autoencoder-keras-tutorial), but I took some layers away.

I don't know, but am I feeding the autoencoder with the tuple generated from the `flow_from_directory` method? Is there a way to cast this tuple into a format the autoencoder accepts?

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Input, Conv2D, 
UpSampling2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT = 112, 112
input_img = Input(shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT,3))

#encoder
def encoder(input_img):
    # 1x112x112x3
    conv1 = Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same') 
    (input_img) 
    # 32x112x112
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv1)
    # 32x56x56
    return pool1

#decoder
def decoder(pool1):
    # 32x56x56
    up1 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(pool1)
    # 32x112x112
    decoded = Conv2D(1,(3,3),activation='sigmoid',padding='same')(up1)
    # 1x112x112
    return decoded

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoder(encoder(input_img)))
autoencoder.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=RMSprop())

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\dataset\train',
    target_size=(112,112),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical')

test_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\dataset\validation',
    target_size=(112,112),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical')

history = autoencoder.fit_generator(
    training_set,
    steps_per_epoch=2790,
    epochs=5,
    validation_data=test_set,
    validation_steps=1145)
```

Here is the model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_14 (InputLayer)        (None, 112, 112, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_42 (Conv2D)           (None, 112, 112, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 56, 56, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_4 (UpSampling2 (None, 112, 112, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_43 (Conv2D)           (None, 112, 112, 1)       289       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,185
Trainable params: 1,185
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I am working with `512x496` OCT images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are building an autoencoder and therefore the output of the model must be the same as the input, there are two problems with your code:

1. You must set the `class_mode` argument of generators to `'input'` to let the labels generated be the same as the generated inputs.
2. The last layer must have 3 filters since the input image has 3 channels: `decoded = Conv2D(3, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're feeding the network the labels, rather than the images. Try setting `class_mode` to `None` explicitly when constructing the data generator -- it defaults to `categorical`.